# How can you syncronize two windows/files that copy zooming and panning in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to do some master studies and I would like to have two files (the original and an empty one) on my screen (each taking half).

I want to have both windows have the same zoom and panning so I have precision. It would be nice if I could also have the same guidelines.

I know that you can do this for the same file in two windows, but I want two files to have this effect.

I haven't been able to find the solution via google.

Comment: Are you in CC? They introduced Artboards in Photoshop CC 2015 that could probably solve this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have photoshop cc. I simply select the zoom tool (looks like a magnifying glass) then select the "zoom all windows" at the top of photoshop.[image: checked box]

You can also make the documents match the zoom by selecting the "window" tab on the top then [Arrange] - [Match Zoom].
[image: window - arrange - match zoom]

I hope that this helps.